# Strategy vs factory pattern in mapping example

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I know this seems weird, but I have situation where both factory and strategy pattern seems like a option. I have some model on FE that I need to map with sort of complicated mapping logic to API format. So i wonder what pattern would be best fit, factory -> because i create objects to send to BE, or strategy -> because there is different operation based on model type?

Thanks!

Comment: what does FE and BE mean in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Strategy and Factory patterns are used for different purposes.
In a strategy pattern, you can interchange the behavior (algorithms).
In the case of a factory pattern, it leaves object creation to the child class. With the factory pattern, you replace complete instance, not the behavior(algorithm) you are interested in.